# How to create trigger based on time period it has to do sum function

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, database-trigger

I want to create a trigger in oracle 11g - every 5 minutes it has to sum the values of  price column in order table. How would i ?

Comment: This doesn't sound like the job for a trigger, but rather a scheduled task of some sort.  Triggers fire when events happen to certain tables.

Comment: Tim, tell me how to acheive this task.

Comment: Use a materialized view

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do this would be to have a materialized view which calculates the total.

```
create table t23 (id number primary key , qty number);

create materialized view log on t23;

create materialized view  t23_total 
refresh force
    start with sysdate + 5/(60*24)
    next sysdate  + 5/(60*24)
as
select sum(qty) as total_qty
from t23
/
```

This is the most efficient way to main a total. This kicks off a refresh every five minutes. If you wanted to maintain the total in real time you could just use

```
create materialized view t23_total 
refresh on commit
as
select sum(qty) as total_qty
from t23
/
```

Answer (score 0):

You may create a scheduler job to run every 5 minutes.

```
declare
   v_anon_block varchar2(500) :=
     q'{begin
          insert into mylog(log_date,total_price) select SYSDATE, SUM(price) 
             from order;
          commit;
        end;}';
 begin
     dbms_scheduler.create_job (
        job_name           =>  'SUM_PRICE_JOB',
        job_type           =>  'PLSQL_BLOCK',
        job_action         =>  v_anon_block,
        start_date         =>  SYSDATE,
        repeat_interval    =>  'FREQ=MINUTELY;INTERVAL=5;',
        enabled            =>  TRUE,
        comments           =>  '5 minute Refresh');
 end;
 /
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to work with "old" data? I mean, what's the purpose in calculating that value every 5 minutes? Have it available in time, live, per request. Create a view or a function that does that, such as

```
create or replace view v_sum_price as
  select sum(price) 
  from orders_table;
```

or

```
create or replace function f_sum_price 
  return number
as
  retval number;
begin
  select sum(price) 
    into retval
    from orders_table;

  return retval;
end;
```

Both of these most probably lack some additional info (order ID? Item ID? Something else?). Furthermore, I can't see a purpose in summing **price** value in orders table. How do you use it? For example, for a restaurant: ORDERS table contains the following prices:

```
ITEM     PRICE   QUANTITY 
Coke       1.5          2
Burger     4.0          2
Wine       2.3          1
Salad      0.8          1
```

and now you know that sum of the PRICE column equals 8.6. What useful information does it contain? Absolutely none (or I can't see it).

Maybe it would  help if you described what problem you're trying to solve.